# How do I make toolbars that look like the ones in Keynote?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

Here's a screenshot of keynote on the ipad:

[image]
<sub>(source: [scottyallen.com](http://scottyallen.com/random/IMG_0009.PNG))</sub>

The toolbar is pretty flat - it doesn't have a vertical gradient the way the builtin toolbar styles do. I've played with the different styles, the translucent flag, and the tint color, and haven't been able to replicate it.

How are they doing this?  How would I implement it?

Answer (score 2):

I think your talking about the `UIToolbar` on top, not the toolbar-ish controls at the bottom.

Changing the looks of a `UINavigationBar` or `UIToolbar` is really easy, you can just use an image instead of the calculated `tintColor` and default gradient.

To do this, you'll need to subclass (or make a category of) the `UINavigationBar` or `UIToolbar` and overwrite the `drawRect:` method, like this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"toolbarBackground.png"];
    [image drawInRect:rect];
}
```

This `image` then gets drawn at the exact `rect` of the `UINavigationBar` or `UIToolbar`, functioning as a background image.